ggplot2 faceting and adding unique labels for each facet in a for loop in R
I am trying to add a unique label to each faceted panel in my plots. Below is the code which I annotated and will describe in detail below:
ebird <- left_join(ebird, cor,  
                   by = c("Species", "region")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Date1.y, -survey.y) %>%
  rename(Date1 = Date1.x) %>%
  mutate(rho = factor(rho)) # added rho, which is what I'm trying to label each plot with


species <- unique(ebird$Species) # 30 species 

for (i in 1:length(species)){    # loop over species
  
  ggplot(ebird[(ebird$Species == species[i]),],
         aes(x = Date1, 
             y = scaled_ebird,
             )) +
    facet_wrap(~region,           # facet by region
               scales = "free", 
               drop = TRUE) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date1, y = scaled_ebird), 
              #color = Species), 
              linewidth = 1) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = scaled_ebird_lower, ymax = scaled_ebird_upper), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date1, y = scaled_survey), linewidth = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date1, y = scaled_survey), pch = 21, fill = "black", size = 3) +
    geom_text(aes(label = rho)) + # attempting to annotate each plot!!!
    scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0.5), 
                 limits = c(as.Date("2022-09-01"), 
                            as.Date("2023-01-31")
                 ), 
                 breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-09-01"),
                                   as.Date("2023-01-31"), 
                                   by ="1 month"),
                 date_labels ="%b", 
                 minor_breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-09-01"), 
                                         as.Date("2023-01-31"), 
                                         by ="1 week")
    ) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    labs(x = NULL, 
         y = "Scaled Relative Abundance",
         title = "") +
    theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    ggtitle(label = paste(species[i], 
                          "Migration Chronology in Michigan", 
                          sep = " ")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
    guides(color = "none")
  
  ggsave(filename = paste("plots/mi/MI_migchron_",species[i],".png", sep = ""),
         height = 10,
         width = 10,
         dpi = 600)
  
}

My problem is that when annotating each plot with rho it labels ALL of them (see image below). Goal I would like to simply annotate each facet with a single number that I turned into a factor (122 levels). Likely a smple fix but can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated.
Example Problem Plot

EDIT New example plot after attempting Jon's solution:


It will be easier for people to help with relevant suggestions if you can share some example data so that we can run the code and try out solutions. For instance, here's a similar sort of graph with data we all have: library(dplyr); storms |> filter(year == 2022) |> ggplot(aes(lubridate::make_datetime(year, month, day, hour), wind)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_text(aes(label = lat)) + facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free")

Guessing that something like geom_text(aes(label = rho), data = . |> dplyr::filter(scaled_ebird == max(scaled_ebird), .by = region)) might work? You want that layer to only one row of data per region, so filtering it or using distinct() or slice() are common ways.

Would you consider using ggrepel package? https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel

Thanks Jon for helping me to provide a reproducible, toy example. I tried your solution below but the label does not facet by region. I've provided another example plot to illustrate above.

Generally, when I want a different label in each facet, I create a new data frame with the labels in one column and the same faceting column(s) as in the data. Then you can give that data frame to geom_text and because the facet information is in the labeling data, the labels show up on the correct facets.

Would it not be easier to show rho in with: facet_wrap(~Species+rho, labeller = label_both)?

Micheal: yes this is much easier. I appreciate the alternative solution - I didn't even consider! Now, is there a way to remove the double facet look? In other words, can facet_wrap  combine the labels in the plot similar to facet_grid (i.e., so the labels aren't separated by black boxes)? I'll leave this open, given that this was an alternative solution (a good one).

You could concatenate the Species and rho and facet by that.

Although this did not answer the question directly, I figured I'd post an answer that was a reasonable (and easier) solution. Credit owed to Michiel and Jon. Instead of adding a geom_label, I faceted based on concatenated group (region and rho). Here's a reproducible example below using the storms data.
library(dplyr) 

storms %>% 
  filter(year == 2022) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(rho = factor(sample(x = -1:1, 1, replace = TRUE)),
         name2 = paste(name, ";", "rho =", rho)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lubridate::make_datetime(year, month, day, hour), wind)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  #geom_text(aes(label = lat)) + 
  facet_wrap(~name2, scales = "free") 


